# About Apple policy for in app links

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

I have read on an article that Apple is applying a policy by which an app can't promote selling another apps, but i dont know the exact details of this. What about a DEMO version that haves a link to the store for the full version? can this still be done?.

If anyone haves more precise information on the subject i'll appreciate it.

Comment: Rather than reading articles, why not read what Apple has to say?

Comment: maybe you are interested in http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30702/app-stores There we could talk about app store policies all day long without all the Offtopic!!!!11111 people

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just not allowed to offer services (in app currency or similar) for app downloads.
You won't have a problem with a link to the pro version in a lite version.
You won't have a problem with a "My App Store" link that shows all your apps either.

Don't reward your users for downloading other apps and you should be good.

Comment: Agreed.  I have several apps with a promotion that cross promotes all the other apps and havent had any problems with Apple.

Comment: I've had a few apps which give the user extra points/money for downloading other apps though.

Comment: "had" might be the keyword. The news about the policy are not even a month old. [Apple Clamps Down On Incentivized App Downloads @ TechCrunch](http://techcrunch.com/2011/04/19/apple-clamps-down-on-incentivized-app-downloads/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+Techcrunch+%28TechCrunch%29). So prepare for rejection on your next update.